# U-SQL : How to merge two usql files with same import statement

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

I want to deploy multiple tables creation script as one adla job to save on cost. I am using packages to get set of defined partition keys for all tables. When i try to deploy as merged script it complains that import statement is declared multiple times and fails.

While i can still deploy script one by one but wanted to see if we can merge script for faster deployment.

Thanks
Amit

Comment: What do you mean by "deploy as merged script" ?

Comment: A merge script which has multiple stored procedures/functions creation statements. In our code repository each object creation is in separate file and we need to currently submit adla job to create those entities in catalog. What we want is to dynamically merge 10-15 scripts in one and then submit adlajob so that we can create multiple objects in one go.

Comment: Is Data Factory here not a solution? You could create a "Preparation" Pipeline in which you define each U-SQL Files as Activity. Before deployment, you might just need to run the pipeline, and that's it...

Comment: That's what I want to avoid. Each file per activity means separate usql job for creation of catalog objects (SP, TVFs). I want to create multiple table creation object in one script but since each table creation statement is referring to same usql package it complains and i have no other choice than creating one table at a time

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I completely get your scenario. If you want to deploy a single object by itself, then that file needs to include all the dependencies (e.g., your package). If you want to deploy several objects, you should include the dependencies only once.

You probably should set up something that generates your script from the underlying "fragments". One fragment would be the reference to the package, the other fragments would be the creation of one object. And your deployment system would concatenate the files as needed.